# Display randomly picked image from Wordpress's page?

Tags: php, wordpress, image, post, random

I would like to display one image at a time on my page, that is picked randomly from the images loaded in this page (from wordpress admin).

I am working with my own theme and I have a "front-page.php" file where I have my function to load the content of my page.

I don't know how to add the random image function to this code.

**my PHP code:**

```html
<?php get_header(); ?> 

<div class="container">

<?php
if ( have_posts() ) {
  while ( have_posts() ) {
    the_post(); 
    $images = [];
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'numberposts' => -1, 'post_status' => null, 'post_parent' => $post->ID ); 
    $attachments = get_posts($args);
    if ($attachments) {
      foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
        $image_url = ( !empty( wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment->ID ) ) ) ? wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment->ID ) : '';
        $image_alt = ( !empty( get_post_meta( $attachment->ID, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true) ) ) ? get_post_meta( $attachment->ID, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true) : '';
        $images[] = array( 
          'url' => $image_url,
          'alt' => $image_alt
        );
      }
    }
    $image = $images[array_rand( $images, 1 )];
    ?>

    <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />

    <?php
  }
}
?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an array of available images and then choose one at random.

```
$images = array(
    'http://via.placeholder.com/350x150',
    'http://via.placeholder.com/350x150',
    'http://via.placeholder.com/350x150',
    'http://via.placeholder.com/350x150',
);
$image_url = $images[array_rand( $images, 1 )];
echo $image_url;
```

If you want to include alt text, use a multidimensional array:

```
$images = array(
    array( 'url' => 'http://via.placeholder.com/350x150', 'alt' => 'My image'),
    array( 'url' => 'http://via.placeholder.com/350x150', 'alt' => 'My image'),
    array( 'url' => 'http://via.placeholder.com/350x150', 'alt' => 'My image'),
    array( 'url' => 'http://via.placeholder.com/350x150', 'alt' => 'My image'),
);
$image = $images[array_rand( $images, 1 )];
echo $image['url'];
echo $image['alt'];
```

From your response it sounds like you're trying to pull the images from the post content, if so, you'll need to loop through the post's attachments to create the images array. However, there are a number of potential pitfalls with this method. If I were you, I would create a gallery field using Advanced Custom Fields and use that as the source of the image group.

```
<?php
if ( have_posts() ) {
  $images = [];
  while ( have_posts() ) {
    the_post(); 
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'numberposts' => -1, 'post_status' => null, 'post_parent' => $post->ID ); 
    $attachments = get_posts($args);
    if ($attachments) {
      foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
        // get url from Plugin: WP Gallery Custom Links
        $image_href = ( !empty( get_post_meta( $attachment->ID, '_gallery_link_url', true) ) ) ? get_post_meta( $attachment->ID, '_gallery_link_url', true) :  '';
        // get attachment
        $image_url = ( !empty( wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment->ID ) ) ) ? wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment->ID ) : '';
        $image_alt = ( !empty( get_post_meta( $attachment->ID, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true) ) ) ? get_post_meta( $attachment->ID, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true) : '';
        $images[] = array( 
          'url' => $image_url,
          'alt' => $image_alt,
          'href' => $image_href // url from WP Gallery Custom Links
        );
      }
    }
  }
  $image = $images[array_rand( $images, 1 )];
  ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $image['href']; ?>" title="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>">
      <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
    </a>

    <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: thanks. Should the link of the array be the link of the page? Because the client will only load the images from Wordpress library to the page and then it should displays one at a time. Every time the page is refreshed the displayed image changes.

Comment: It should be the URL of the image.  If you need to link the image to another page add a href value to the array.

Comment: Ok I see. But the client shouldn't touch the php or any code. So I am looking for a function that could detects the images present in the page (because the client had loaded them by the Wordpress admin) and then displays only one at a time. The images selection that the client makes will often change, so I need a code that doesn't need to be changed.

Comment: How did they add images to the page, via the WYSIWYG editor?

Comment: yes they add images via the WYSIWYG editor. Well, the random function is king of working but it shows images that are not from the article. It picks two different images from the site… Here is the [link](http://temporarygallery.org/do-not-remove-this-folder/) of the page where you can see the result.

Comment: @Lolo Make sure you're within the post loop. https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop

Comment: @Lolo If you're not in the loop, the $post->ID value will be incorrect.

Comment: @Lolo Just saw your update. Looks like you need the while( have_posts() ) and the_post();

Comment: `while( have_posts() )` and `the_post()` are in place, nothing happened..

Comment: @Lolo You'll have to move the array outside the while loop.   $images = []; should be prior to the while loop and $image = $images[array_rand( $images, 1 )]; should be after it.

Comment: it still doesn't show anything… I have used the last updated code of your answer.

Comment: Your source code is displaying an error that says the array you're attempting to grab the random index from is empty.  Are you're images attached?

Comment: My images are content of the post. When in my post editor, I do "add a media" and I chose few images, then I save it. They are not specificly attributed to this page (but they are loaded into it). They also appear on other post. But since this page is my homepage, I would like to display random image that I can specificaly choose.

Comment: The images are probably not attached to the post.  Go to the Media Library and switch to the list view.  Find your image, click the 'Attach' link on the 'Uploaded To' column and then choose the page that you're using as your front page.

Comment: Can't they be attached to multiple pages or posts ? You are right, they are not attached to the homepage, but they appear as attached to the article they are in and I don't think I can add several attachment?

Comment: Or, will it affects my posts if I unattached them from the post they are already attached to, in regard to attach them to the homepage then?

Comment: You have three choices:  1) upload the images twice, 2) assign the images to the front-page or 3) create a gallery field using custom fields.

Comment: I am coming back with the code you have written. The function works, but only half way. Every images are link and are clickable. It must have something wrong that I can't find in the code, that is not activating their link.

Comment: @Lolo There is no link base on the example page you previously shared.  I'm going to need to see an example of the issue.

Comment: sorry it might be not clear. As we discussed it, I have made a media gallery in my page, in which the images are attached to this page. The function you gave, makes these images showing up one at a time in a random order by refreshing the page. The issue I didn't noticed earlier is: I am using the [WP Gallery Custom Links](https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-gallery-custom-links/) plugin that able me to add links to these images, so there are clickable and get us to some other pages. When your php function is active, the links don't work anymore because the images are not clickable…

Comment: I have the feeling the function kind of hides the links. [Here](http://temporarygallery.org/do-not-remove-this-folder/) is the page where you can see the issue.

Comment: @Lolo I think you can access the URL with this: get_post_meta( $attachment->ID, '_gallery_link_url', true )

Comment: I tried but it didn't change. Yet I am not sure if I have edited the code correctly… Could you update the code in your answer?

Comment: actually the images are attached to the page, so, even if I don't add a gallery in the page it loads the attached images from de media library. But still, I don't think it gets the link url

Comment: @Lolo Try to mimic how I accessed `_wp_attachment_image_alt` for  `_gallery_link_url` inside the foreach loop.

Comment: I am not sure how to mimic the code. I am beginner in PHP, if you don't mind could you update the code in your answer?

Comment: Add `print_r( get_post_meta( $attachment->ID, '_gallery_link_url', true) );` as the first line inside the foreach loop and post the output.  This will hopefully output your URL.

Comment: Ok I have placed the code! It is showing up the link as text and not as a clickable image… you can see it [here](http://temporarygallery.org/do-not-remove-this-folder/)

Comment: Cool, now instead of printing the `_gallery_link_url` data, add it to the `images[]` array.  You should be able to access it just like `$image['url']` or `$image['alt']` and use it create a link.

Comment: your solution works perfectly! Than you very much :)